# Abrir modal con id de la publicación

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

estoy haciendo un modal para manejar los comentarios de una publicación realizada, tengo mi componente `comments` donde me abre el modal y tiene toda la información y le mando los `post` así

```
<Comments post={ posts }/>
```

Lo que recibo de esas `props` es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de que cuando le de a mi boton de la publicación me traiga el `ID` correspondiente a esa publicación

```
export const Comments = ({ post }) => {
  console.log(post)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    
    setOpen(true);
  }
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([1,2,3,4]);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);
  const us = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = () =>{

    // console.log();
    const finalComment = `${us.authData.displayName}: ${comment}`
    dispatch(commentPost(finalComment, post._id));
  }


  return (
    <>
      <img
        src={Comment}
        alt=""
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
          width: "auto",
          maxHeight: "20rem",
          objectFit: "cover",
          borderRadius: "0.5rem",
        }}
        onClick={handleOpen}
      />
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Box
              component="img"
              sx={{
                height: "3rem",
                width: "3rem",
                maxHeight: { xs: "3rem", md: "3rem" },
                maxWidth: { xs: "3rem", md: "3rem" },
                borderRadius: "50%",
              }}
              alt="Profile Photo"
              src={user.profilePicture}
            ></Box>
```

Estuve tratando de varias maneras pero o me sale `undefined` o simplemente me retorna todo el `array` completo, requiero acceder a dicho `id` ya que en mi función `handleClick` necesito ese `ID` para poder realizar el comentario pero pues así como lo tengo me manda undefined

Comment: Por que comments recibe posts??  La publicacion debe recibir comments en teoría. Imaginando la lógica de tu aplicación iteras Posts para representar cada Post(Este tiene la info de esa publicacion), luego iteras los comentario de esa publicacion o haces una búsqueda de todos los comentario de esa publicacion para luego abrir el modal y mostrarlos todos ( a cada comments le puedes pasar el id de Posts)

Comment: Agregar la lógica donde empleas el componente Comments para saber quien le pasa la info y en donde puede estar el error.